# Need first output to be a number, but its that numbers concatenation

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class QuestionOne {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberofDays;
    int sharePoints;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
    numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Share points on the first day: ");
    sharePoints = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (numberofDays < 10 || numberofDays > 20) {
      System.out.println("The number of days doesn’t meet the required criteria, enter it again");
      System.out.print("Number of days in the period: ");
      numberofDays = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Day " + " Share Points");
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberofDays; i++) {
      if (numberofDays % 2 == 0)
        if (i <= numberofDays / 2) {
          sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
          System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
        } else {
          sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
          System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
        }
      else {
        if (i <= numberofDays / 2 + 1) {
          sharePoints = sharePoints + 50;
          System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
        } else {
          sharePoints = sharePoints - 25;
          System.out.println(i + "    " + sharePoints);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This code should output to something like (as an example if the user were to enter the values 11 for the day and 550 for share price):

```
Day Share Points
1 550
2 600
3 650
4 700
5 750
6 800
7 775
8 750
9 725
10 700
11 675
```

however when I enter 11 for the day, and 550 for the share price, my code looks like:

```
Day Share Points
1 600
2 650
3 700
4 750
5 800
6 850
7 825
8 800
9 775
10 750
11 725
```

From what I can tell according to my code, I have coded it so that it adds 50 every time until the number six- whereas I want it to display the first number as the user enters it in, then to start adding and subtracting accordingly (note that everything is as I want it in my output except for the first number, and the proceeding numbers, as a result, being different). My wording may not be very accurate, but I hope the example outputs are enough to explain what I want as my output.

Comment: This is the perfect time to 1. learn to indent your code and make it readable (even for you); 2. learn to use a debugger. A professor doctor should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it can be useful to process a base case before a for loop.

In your case that would look like printing the appropriate line for day 1 and then starting your loop at i=2 instead of i=1.

Comment: when I try to print another line (since I've already defined share price as share price + (number)) it tells me that there is an error and that it cannot find symbol

Comment: I figured it out, I just moved that statement outside of the loop